# Stack Overflow verification email not delivered to Hey inbox when updating email address

Tags: bug, email, email-verification

Unless there is a significant delay in sending verification emails when updating your Stack Exchange email address (read: +4 hours), I think the verification email sending is bugged.

I just wanted to check - is there any way a Firefox plugin like [Ghostery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostery) (tracker blocker) or [Adblock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus) would prevent the verification email from being triggered?

**Reproduction Steps**

1. Go to your profile and email settings page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current
2. enter your new email address and hit <kbd>Save</kbd>
3. make sure the "verify your email address" message appears (visual confirmation that the change request has been received - refreshing the page should show your new, unverified email address too)

The email hasn't come through and I've checked my *Spam* folder (and my trash folder just in case). I've also tried using the "Resend verification" link.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you tried looking in your Junk mail?

Comment: Yes yes :) that's what I meant by checking my Spam folder (junk mail is called Spam in the Hey web app)

Comment: I did that few days ago, email eventually arrived more than 12 hours later (read the next day). Something is not working properly.

Comment: Still no email and it's been over 24 hours

Comment: Mind pairing this up with a support request from the contact form at the bottom? It should get the attention of staff that way.

Comment: Oh! sorry, I guess I misread or didn’t notice… Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked our email backend. According to SendGrid, the email was relayed and delivered to your address successfully. Can you check for any emails from `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email`? I'm not sure there's much more we can do given that it left our system successfully!

Answer (score 1):

My apologies. The [Hey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hey_(email_service)) web app was delivering everything from `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email` into The Feed (a separate inbox) - I think this happened because I chose to have the Stack Overflow newsletter delivered into the feed.

The unintended side effect is that since account emails as well as the newsletter are delivered from the same email address (as opposed to, say `newsletter-no-reply@stackoverflow.email`), at the time of writing there is no way for the Hey client to tell the difference (hopefully us Hey subscribers see the ability to add email filter rules based on subject line soon!).

Posting this answer here for clarity in case someone else is using Hey and is missing some verification emails - it was not a SO/SE problem.